# Что такое кластер?

Tags: терминология

Постоянно слышу термин кластер, но всегда остаюсь не в теме. Может кто прояснить для чайника,что это значит

Comment: Постоянно слышите где? В каком контексте?

Comment: А без знания контекста получится ответить только [определением из словаря](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80), наверное

Comment: Вика о [кластерах](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80_(%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BF%D0%B0_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D1%8C%D1%8E%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Кластер это объединение нескольких однородных элементов, которое может рассматриваться как самостоятельная единица, обладающая определёнными свойствами.

Например у тебя есть 5 штук Raspberry Pi. собираешь их в один кластер.
С серверами такая же ерунда. Есть стойка с 10 серверами объединил и у тебя 1 большой мощный сервер.

Comment: Коллекция - это объект, способный хранить группу одинаковых элементов. Получается кластер - почти тоже самое,что коллекция ?)

Comment: :)не могу не согласится.

Comment: @D.Nursultan Вы смешиваете контексты употребления слов. Возможно, именно поэтому вам ничего и не понятно. Ну, либо это такой осознанный троллинг местных.